# Why isn't PHP's STDIN defined when operating with Apache?

Tags: php, linux, apache, stdin

I am operating PHP Version 5.5.24 on Centos 6.  http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php seems to imply that I should use the defined constant `STDIN`, however, as shown when executed with Apache, it is not defined.

```
<?php
$input = fgets(STDIN);
```

> Notice: Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN' in
>   /var/www/bidjunction/html/stdin.php on line 2
>
> Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in
>   /var/www/bidjunction/html/stdin.php on line 2

EDIT.  It is defined from the CLI.  Let me update the title.

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$ php -r 'echo(STDIN);'
Resource id #1
[Michael@devserver ~]$
```

Comment: `stdin` is a FILE HANDLE, not a constant. you can use it in fread/fwrite-type operations, but it's not something you can use in echo/print. it's not a traditional `define()`'d constant.

Comment: @MarcB  `$input = fgets(STDIN);` results in an undefined error as well.  Also, see my edited post about the CLI.

Comment: stdin/stdout are also generally only available in CLI php.

Comment: You mentioned Apache. Do you serve php via `php-fpm` or are you using that super shitty `mod_php`?

Comment: @N.B.  Probably the later.  How can I check?

Comment: Do you just want to accept raw input sent to an Apache session? Maybe you want `file_get_contents("php://input")`?

Comment: Open your apache's config file and look for `mod_php` I guess. It's been ages since I used it. The problem is that SAPI implementation dictates many things, also what Marc said - STDIN/STDOUT are generally available and used when you run the CLI binary. What is it you want to solve by using STDIN anyway?

Comment: @N.B.  Messing around with a UDP client.  See http://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-php/.

Comment: @MarcB `stdin/stdout are also generally only available in CLI php`.  Is there a workaround from using within Apache?

Comment: Those are CLI scripts and the tutorial even tells you so. Why would you involve serving php via Apache for that then? What input are you supposed to fetch if you serve anything via Apache? Something's missing here.

Comment: @N.B.  Just experimenting.  Didn't realize the scripts couldn't be run through Apache.

Comment: Well, they can be run through Apache but it's not really sensible to do so. You can always open your own resource handle towards a stream, but why would you do so? The UDP server really makes 0 sense to serve through Apache. Client could be served through Apache but then again - why? You can rewrite the client to accept parameters via HTTP ($_GET or $_POST), but you need to alter the script in that case - remove the `while` and so on.

Comment: Thank you all.  This is a brand new subject for me, but I now agree it doesn't make sense to do so through Apache which is why I was likely getting the errors.

Comment: FWIW, `STDIN` only seems to be defined by the CLI SAPI: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

Comment: @deceze That makes sense as there is no `STDIN` for mod_php (it lives in the Apache process) and CGI uses `STDIN` internally (and messing with it is a bad idea).

Comment: Not that I still need an answer, but I would rather not delete this post as it might benefit others, and I would feel guilty posting my own answer based on all your great comments.  Anyone want to post a quick answer?

Comment: Please note that `stdin` is available also within Apache, and contains the body of the request, so POST and PUT methods. Another condition is that php does not handle it, which it does for content types `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 0):

Per deceze's comment.

> FWIW, STDIN only seems to be defined by the CLI SAPI:
>   php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php